# Rotate symbol base on polyline angle

Tags: autocad, angles

I am using AcadMap to bring in .shp files for polylines. I have AutoCAD tickmark block at midpoint but it is at 0 degrees (straight up).

Is there any way to rotate block angle to match polyline angle?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Revised 1:52 pm

The .shp file contains lines representing electric power lines which has object data attached. (Length of line, material, etc.)

The block is in AutoCAD with attributes. In the MAPIMPORT dialog box under Point Mapping you can tell esri to use certain blocks to represent esri symbols. The block comes in ok, but it is not aligned with line.
(See attachment)[image: Dialog Box].

I would like for esri to rotate block to align with line.[image: ACAD Block]

Comment: help us understand. Is the tic mark just one of the polylines in your shapefile? Do you want to rotate all of the data (as in rotate the dataframe)? If your tic mark is a point the symbol can be rotated with either a field value or a constant (manual). Please respond to the questions by clicking edit on your original question and give as much information as you can. perhaps a screen shot even.